# Material-ui react grid - how to change pagination bottom toolbar label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Current datagrid implementation shows: - of totalrows**

[image]

Above design is default in Datagrid.
Using datagrid from

> "@mui/x-data-grid": "latest",

> import { DataGrid , GridOverlay} from "@mui/x-data-grid";

needed below design instead

[image]

code :

```
const [pageState, setPageState] = useState({
    page: 0, //TODO: need to change 
    pageSize: DEFAULT_PAGESIZE,//TODO: need to change 
  });
<DataGrid
          pagination
          rowCount={count}
          {...pageState}
          loading={isLoading}
          rows={rowsData}
          paginationMode="server"
          columns={columns}
          onRowClick={handleCellClick}
          onPageChange={(page) => setPageState((prev) => ({ ...prev, page }))}
          onPageSizeChange={(pageSize) =>
            setPageState((prev) => ({ ...prev, pageSize }))
          }
          components={{
            NoRowsOverlay: customNoRowsOverlay,
            Toolbar: DashboardSearchBar
          }}
          componentsProps={{
            toolbar: {
              value: "",
              filtersData: filtersData,
              onChange: handleChange,
              orderStatuses: masterData?.orderStatuses,
              clearSearch: () => handleChange("orderAutoId", ""),
              applyFilter: applyFilter,
              clearFilter: clearFilter,
              isFilterApplied: isFilterApplied
            },
          }}
        />
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: what is your datagrid implementation? codesandbox would help. you haven't given enough information to even begin to fathom what might be wrong.

Comment: added most of it @SangeetAgarwal. can't add full implementation due to limitation

Comment: check these two links https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/#pagination and  https://mui.com/components/pagination/

Comment: Hello, did you find a way to change label pagination in Datagrid ?